# How to use iOS 11 Large title and default title together

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, ios11

I have used

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setPrefersLargeTitles:YES]
```

for large title. But i would like to show both the default title and large title together, the way whatsapp shows on no internet condition.

something like this. How to add both navigation titles , the large one and the default one ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The default title you are talking about is actually `prompt` text.

However if you want an `UIActivityIndicator` along with text. You have to use `titleView` property of `UINavigationBar`. Like

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *aiView = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    aiView.hidesWhenStopped = NO; //just to make it visible
    self.navigationItem.titleView = aiView;
```

and set it to nil when you want to hide.

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = nil;
```

See below links for detail

[UINavigationController Promt](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationitem/1624930-prompt), [Navigation Bar](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationbar)

Comment: True but how to display both 1) Default title view and 2) Large text Title view ?

Comment: Large title is iOS 11.0 compatible. You can show both. `self.title` & `self.navigationItem.titleView`. iOS less than 11 will only show titleView instead of title. For previous versions you have to subclass UINavigationController to create your own navigation controller.